# Teamviewer remote screen flashes disappears

Tags: teamviewer

When I try to use the remote control to access a remote PC, the client screen flashes and disappears. I searched "ask ubuntu" - nothing there that worked

Comment: Hi and welcome. Sorry this does not sound like a Ubuntu question it sounds like an issue with teamviewer.

Comment: I was afraid of that. However, TV worked fine until I updated the Linux Kernel

Comment: I just tried it on an older version of ubuntu it worked. That's what I'll do until the bugs are fixed, or the world ends